# Chrome Extension ID used in url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, google-chrome-extension

In my Chrome Extension I open a new tab with an index.html. Everything works fine except the displayed url. The url contains my extension id. This looks very long an ugly. Is there a way to prevent that or to change it?
Here an example with addblockers id this it what it looks like

chrome-extension://cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb/index.html`

Comment: Nope, there's no way.

Comment: unless you override the chrome new tab, or inject a content script on your own site hosted somewhere else, then no.

Comment: OK, then I have to accept this. Thanks :)